# How to make image full resolution on wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, resolution

I'm having trouble making an image that I inserted into the page full resolution. When you click on the image, it directs to a new page and it's full resolution, but when it's in the page, it's low resolution. How can I make it the actual resolution instead of a lower resolution than it actually is?

Answer (score 0):

When you add an image under the "attachment display settings"  choose the size you would like to display.

More info here https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages#Step_5_.E2.80.93_Attachment_Display_Settings